# Php includes performance hit

Tags: php, performance, include, require, execution-time

```
<?php   
$t1 = microtime(true);

require("File0.inc"); // size: 7.0 kB
include("File1.inc"); // size: 30.8 kB 
include("File2.php"); // size: 99.0 kB 
require('File3.php'); // size: 1.6 kB 

echo "{includes: ".(microtime(true) - $t1)." seconds}";
?>
```

This out puts between 0.013 seconds to 0.018 seconds.
This is really inefficient for me, my code (after it) runs in about 0.0002 seconds.
How can I minimize the execution time taken on including the files?

Comment: @Joe, it will be noticeable if 50 users come at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Including PHP files takes time, there's no way around it.

If the loading time really is such a big issue for you, you may have to just put all the code into one big file. But that's a nightmare when it comes to modularization and code quality, of course, so you should really consider getting a faster server instead of doing this.

Meanwhile, you could try caching your output using [memcached](http://memcached.org/) or [APC](https://www.php.net/apc) to improve loading times.

Comment: What if one of the files it just a big associative array?

Comment: put the big associative array in a mem based key value store such as memcached or redis.

Comment: I used http://il1.php.net/apc and it made the performance 4-5 times better, add it to the answer so others could use it (tell them that it is automatic).

Comment: done. not sure what you mean by automatic in this context, tho. :)

Comment: If you just apt-get the APC mod then it will work it's magic automatically, that is what I mean I thought at the beginning that I had to manually cache all of the objects in the files.